# reload only elements of the certain class on click - jquery

Tags: function, reload, element, jquery

I have the function which reloads page on click:

```
$('#reload').click(function () {
   location.reload();
 });
```

What should I put instead of `location.reload();` in order to reload only elements with aaa class?

tried `$('.aaa').reload();` - doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you want to reload it from? you have a url which gets contents for that element?

Comment: it's just on page html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the contents to an element, i.e provided you have a url that returns the html to be loaded into the element. You cannot just reload an element to an old state because *HTML is stateless* unless you manage the state manually.

```
  $('#reload').click(function () {
      $('.aaa').load(url); //url which returns you the content of the html.
 });
```

or other way could be storing the previous state of the element in localstorage/cookie/data cache etc and populate it back on the click.

An example for second way is:

```
 $('#reload').click(function () {
      $('.aaa').replaceWith($('.aaa').data('cache')); //just replace itself with one in the data cache
 });

$('.aaa').data('cache', $('.aaa').clone(true)); //on load of the page save the current element in data cache, for later use
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbQKh/)**

Comment: correct answer. Only thing is that I've asked the wrong question, but your answer definitely helped. thanks.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! I am surprised it's not more popular as it's very useful even after 3 years